# Angular 2 is not installing using npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

While installing angular 2 it shows the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ic020019\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular@2"

npm ERR! node v4.4.2

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5

npm ERR! No compatible version found: angular@2
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 1.5.8, 1.5.7, 1.5.6, 1.5.5, 1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.0-rc.2, 1.5.0-rc.1, 1.5.0-rc.0, 1.5.0-beta.2, 1.5.0-beta.0, 1.4.12, 1.4.11, 1.4.10, 1.4.9, 1.4.8, 1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.4.4
, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.0-rc.2, 1.4.0-rc.1, 1.4.0-rc.0, 1.4.0-beta.6, 1.4.0-beta.5, 1.4.0-beta.4, 1.4.0-beta.3, 1.4.0-beta.2, 1.4.0-beta.1, 1.4.0-beta.0, 1.3.20, 1.3.19, 1.3.18, 1.3.1
7, 1.3.16, 1.3.15, 1.3.14, 1.3.13, 1.3.12, 1.3.11, 1.3.10, 1.3.9, 1.3.8, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.4-build.3588, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.0-rc.5, 1.2.30, 1.2.29, 1.2.28, 1.2.27, 1.
2.23, 1.2.22, 1.2.21, 1.2.20, 1.2.19, 1.2.18, 1.2.17, 1.2.16, 1.2.15, 1.2.14, 1.2.13, 1.2.12, 1.2.11, 1.2.10, 1.2.9, 1.2.8, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.5, 1.1.4,
 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.8, 1.0.7, 1.0.6, 1.0.5, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1, 0.0.1-2, 0.0.1-1
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\SSP\angular 2 POC\npm-debug.log
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: To install Angular2 and setup basic application, simply follow this article - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 2 is in a different package than angular 1: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2

For example, you could install it using `npm install angular2`.

Comment: Thank you.. i was tried with npm install angular@2 now its working with "npm install angular2" :)

Comment: @MaheshK Just FYI... By running 'npm install angular2' you will get 2.0.0-beta.17 version. Current Angular2 version is 2.0.0-rc.4

Answer (score 2):

To install Angular2 you can use the command `npm install angular2`.  Another way of doing it is to add the package and version number to your package.json file.  For example:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17"`
}
...
```

You then need to run `npm install` in your project root.

**However** .... I wouldn't use the Angular2 npm package, because it's a little out of date now (at the time of writing, this may change after full release).  The development team has split the main areas of functionality into separate sub-packages.  To use these you will need to import them individually into your package.json file.  For Example:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2"
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Installation of the current version of [Angular 2](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular) is split up into several packages:

- [@angular/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core)
- [@angular/common](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/common)
- [@angular/platform-browser-dynamic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic)
- [@angular/platform-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/platform-browser)
- [@angular/http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http)
- [@angular/forms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/forms)
- [@angular/router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/router)

Just install all of those with `npm install`